# Application showing CORS error after sometime (AZURE AD)

Tags: azure, spring-boot, spring-security, azure-active-directory

I am using Spring Boot + Azure AD + angular9 and using azure ad default provided api to get access to my application.
After launching application Microsoft login appear -> verify creds -> show me my landing page. All api works fine.
But after sometime (almost 5-6 mins) all api start failing.
It showing **CORS ERROR**  in browser console.

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code
&client_id=<client_id>
&scope=openid%20https://graph.microsoft.com/user.read&state=lZfrMwK0nx5kQDjO56DJsMTFhcuvDmU5o0-ZCvTPvI4%3D
&redirect_uri=https://{abc}.com/login/oauth2/code/azure&nonce=CCGwfpb4klAiPtEApCs3nS8ICod0-htdHWvBATNYfXs' 
  (redirected from 'https://{abc}.com/api/supplier/add') from origin
 'https://{abc}.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: 
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

for every api onwards it is showing CORSS ERROR

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?
response_type=code&client_id=<client_id>
&scope=openid%20https://graph.microsoft.com/user.read
&state=LAJfYfn9XFOISAHO4Cq4iA5_Dkya3CFDXKgQmQVfpxg%3D
&redirect_uri=https://{abc}.com/login/oauth2/code/azure
&nonce=IBF8nVnrWhH-SY9VpNxouZcxn_6JZEo3J_d-JBHTAK4. 
(Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing)
```

Here is my Web-Security-config

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    
    @Value("${logout.url}")
    String logoutUrl;
    
    @Value("${redirect.url}")
    String redirectUrl;
    
    @Autowired
    private OAuth2UserService<OidcUserRequest, OidcUser> oidcUserService;
    
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        
        String logoffUrl = logoutUrl+"?post_logout_redirect_uri="+URLEncoder.encode(redirectUrl, "UTF-8");
        
         http
         .csrf().disable()
             .authorizeRequests()
             .anyRequest().authenticated()
             .and()
             .oauth2Login()
             .userInfoEndpoint()
             .oidcUserService(oidcUserService);
         
         http.logout().logoutUrl("/api/logout")
            .invalidateHttpSession(true)
            .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
            .logoutSuccessUrl(logoffUrl) ;
    }

}
```

WebMvcConfig

```
@Configuration
public class WebMvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer{
    
    @Value("${spring.allowed.origin}")
    public String allowedOrigin;

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**")
            .allowedOrigins(allowedOrigin)
            .allowedMethods("GET", "POST")
            .allowCredentials(true)
            .maxAge(3600);
    }
    
    
    @Override
    public void configurePathMatch(PathMatchConfigurer configurer) {
        UrlPathHelper urlPathHelper = new UrlPathHelper();
        urlPathHelper.setUrlDecode(false);
        configurer.setUrlPathHelper(urlPathHelper);
    }
}
```

From angular side I am sending header like below

```
headers = new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' : '*',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': 'true',
  });
```

Please help.. thanks

Comment: It looks like you have configured redirect-based authentication in your back-end API. Technically speaking the correct solution for these cases is to implement the authentication in the front-end SPA and implement token authentication in the back-end. This means if the request has a valid token and the user is authorized to do the request, it returns a 200 OK. If the token is not valid, it should return a 401. The reason you are getting a CORS error is because your back-end is trying to redirect the AJAX request to AAD, which won't accept it.

Comment: You can use for example MSAL.js to acquire access tokens in the front-end application. It will manage expiry etc. for you and allow you to send the user to login when needed.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. :) Trying it now.

Comment: I tried to create SPA in angular 9 using @azure/msal-angular. 
While login there is only id-token in payload. I am not getting any other detail like username, group, expiry-date etc in the payload. Do I have to fetch all these by extracting the token. or any other way is possible ? Please help

Comment: After signing in with your account, you could get the account messages with [`getAccount()` method](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@azure/msal-angular#login-and-acquiretoken-apis).

Comment: @SheshanathKumar Has this issue been resolved? Any updates?

Comment: @AllenWu yes issue resolved. Thanks for asking

Comment: @SheshanathKumar Can you post an answer to help others who may have the same issue?

Answer (score 0):

I implemented SPA using angular msal service.
I use loginPopUp method to get login pop up provided by Microsoft. It solve my ADFS security issue also.
Here I am not using any accessTokenSilent / accessTokenRedirect method to get access token after the previous token expire.
I added CSP header in my nginx.conf file (web server conf file), so after the token expire it automatically providing me new access token on click of any api.

header for CSP added in nginx.conf file

```
add_header Content-Security-Policy "frame-ancestors 'self';"  always;
```